Spark AR Login Failed 2024
I tried to log in to the Spark AR application using Facebook, but when I logged in, I couldn't click continue, and it caused me to get stuck and unable to proceed. How can I solve this problem? Thank you.
I have tried with different versions but the result is still the same.
